# We have a 5 hr layover in Osaka do we need a transit visa?

Tags: japan, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, osaka

We are Filipino Citizens moving to Canada via Jetstar and Air Canada. Our flight itinerary brings us to Osaka for a 5 hr layover before our next flight. We'd like to know if we need to have a VISA for that short amount of stay?

Comment: Do you have separate tickets?  If yes, do you have checked-in luggage?

Comment: Jetstar is oneworld, and pretty limited in its codesharing and baggage interlining. AC is Star Alliance. Separate tickets and passing through immigration to recheck baggage are very likely.